# @davidjbradshaw's iframe-resizer, iframe width not resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe-resizer

I'm working currently on a widget project, where you click on a button and a bubble opens above. All this is within a dynamically created iframe. I am using the Iframe-Resizer of @davidjbradshaw to resize the iframe depending on the content. The height-resizing works perfectly so far. My problem is when I close the bubble after opening it, the width of the iframe doesn't resize back to the original size.

Here is the **html** within the iframe

```
<div class="content">
<div id="bubble_wrapper" class="bubble_wrapper hide">
    <div id="speech-bubble" class="speech-bubble">
        <div class="widget-content">';
            <p class="introduction" style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:small;"> intro </p>
            <hr>
            <p class="social-media"> MESSENGERS </p>'
            <div class="providers-imgs">
                <a>..</a>
                <a>..</a>
                <a>..</a>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble_arrow"></div>
</div>
<div id="logo_wrapper">
    <div id="logo-button" style="background-color:#F1E9F1;">
        <img id="logo" src="/img/o-icon.png" style="width:38px; height:38px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the **javascript** code for showing and hiding the bubble:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

var _isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i);

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(buildHeader());
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = buildHtml();
addListeners()

function addListeners() {
    var bubble = document.getElementById('bubble_wrapper');
    var logo = document.getElementById('logo');

    logo.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (_isMobile) logo_wrapper.classList.add('hide')

        if (bubble.classList.contains('hide'))
            bubble.classList.remove('hide')

        else
            bubble.classList.add('hide')

    }, false)
```

I tried to change the width of the iframe within the EventListener() but it didn't work. 
What I also noticed is after I close the bubble the iframe-width stays as it still contains the bubble and when I inspect it it looks like the logo-button has margin-right although I've set margins to 0.

Does anyone have same or similar problem when working with the iframe-resizer? Any suggestions, tips or help would be appreciated.

Here a screenshot of the app, because it still runs only locally. 
https://drive.google.com/a/orat.io/file/d/0B12BLLTyY7C2TEhPTnFVMHBHTkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you initialize the iframeResizer with the option "sizeWidth" turned on? `$('iframe').iFrameResize({sizeWidth:true});` . Also, please post images to a publicly accessible site, like Imgur

Answer (score 0):

You can force the iframe to resize from JS with.

```
myIFrame.iframeResizer.size()
```

If that doesn't work then the issue is likely with your HTML.

Comment: Yeah, it was more like bad logic from my side :) I fixed it, just took out the part causing the problem out of the iframe and it worked perfectly :) Thanks!